# How to keep an item in focus when switching to another another view in my tvOS application

Tags: swift, focus, tvos

I'm making a video app with collection views. My app can show a video of the selected cell in a collection view and it all works like the way I want it to be. When it shows a video the cell loses it focuses. When the video is done with playing it does focus the correct cell, but I want it to look like it was already in focus. (right now it animates it)

Does anyone know how I could do something like this?

**Edit**

I am using 'adjust image when focused' for the image in the cells of my collection view

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad set "self.collectionView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true"

Comment: As I said: When the video is done with playing it does focus the correct cell, but I want it to look like it was already in focus.